# Problem with SAPUI5 odata date field (smart table)

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm creating app in the SAPUI5 and I am using mock data, where I have fields with date time type. In layout I'm using smart filter bar and smart table to show items. 
When I want to filter by date, I am selecting date, which I am interested in, and in selected items container, chosen data is incorrect - the day is like -1.

I would like to mention that I want to filter only by date (without time) and I can't get inside to properties date picker.

Is there any possible solution or somebody had the same issues?

[image]

Comment: "I can't get inside to properties date picker...", does that mean you can't edit the code?

Comment: no, I can, but in sapui5 smartTable/smartFilterBar are "ready to use" elements and there is no code in my IDE. I mean that all features connected with that are  loading to my project via XHR.  The only thing what I am doing is calling proper item in XML view, the rest is happening outside the stage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with my projects .. so the only solution i found is that you need format the date by your own in the controller..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting

`customData:dateFormatSettings='\{"UTC":true\}'`

on the SmartFilterBar?

A while back that solved issues for us.